# Perform Espresso test and fail if an EditText is empty

Tags: android, android-espresso

Android Studio 2.1.2

I am trying to get the test to fail if the user clicks on a button and the username is empty. This is my code below. However, the test always passes. Is there a way to do the test so it will fail if the `EditText` is empty.

```
@Test
public void shouldFailToLoginWithEmptyUserName() {
     onView(withId(R.id.btnSignIn)).perform(ViewActions.click());
     onView(withId(R.id.etUsername)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withText("")));
}
```

Comment: What does your app do in this use case (i.e. when the user clicks on a button when the username is empty)? This behavior is probably what you should test. The test should be designed to pass when the app behaves correctly. A test which fails on bad input from the user is not well designed because failing tests should indicate that the app has a bug.

Comment: If you do want to check for an empty string, you can use `check(matches(withText(isEmptyString())))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tests should only fail when the code being tested does not work correctly. A test which is designed to fail because it emulates bad user input is not well-designed. Instead, the test should check that the app responds correctly when the user misbehaves. For example, if the app displays an error message after the user clicks the "Sign In" button without entering a user name, then the test should check that the error message is displayed correctly. Such a test will pass when the app is implemented correctly and fail when there is a bug.